# How to create cookie to work between php webservice and android?

Tags: php, android, cookies

I am going to create cookie to work between php webservice and android. I already create the cookie on php, here is the code :

```
$name = 'namenamaname';
$password = 'passwordrahasia';
$latitude = -7.952551000;
$longitude = 112.614443000;

$seal_cookie = "$name, $password, $latitude, $longitude";
$seal_cookies = base64_encode(serialize($seal_cookie));

setcookie ("SealCookie", $seal_cookies, time()+60);
```

the question is, how do I send the cookie in to android client? Do I have to add some code also in the client? or Do I have to create the client cookie?

Comment: I don't think that third part cookies are good. and I think your approach is also un-secure.

Comment: what do you mean with the third part cookie? sorry, I don't get it